# Longest chain of pair of points

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, partial-order

For chaining two points A and B

```
A(x1,y1) at index i in array
B(x2,y2) at index j in array

//condition
if ( i<j and x1<=x2 and y1<=y2 and !(x1==x2 and y1==y2))
    then A and B are in a increasing sequence (chain)
```

For example:
A = { (0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (2,1), (2,0)}

longest sequence (cahin) is = {(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (2,1)} i.e 4 elements

we have to find the longest sequence (chain) of points.

How to approach for this?

solution required is less than O(N^2)

Possible solutions:-
1) [LIS (NlogN) link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence)
2) Posets (I don't understand if you can explain)

Comment: We can't explain a solution you haven't told us!

Comment: I means how to implement this for my conditions or any new way to solve this problem

Comment: Have you tried reading about standard algorithms for longest increasing subsequence?  Can they be applied here?  Please spend some time studying those standard materials, then edit your question to summarize why they don't apply (or, if they do apply, then you know how to answer your question and can write an answer below).

Comment: I applied working in O(Nlog^2N) but all test cases are not passed :(